# Positions of RealmObjects change on deletion

Tags: java, android, realm

Let’s say i have three objects/elements in my realm database:-

1. A
2. B
3. C

When i delete the first element (i.e A) using the method`deleteFromRealm()`, the positions of the remaining two objects change like this:-

1. C
2. B

instead of:-

1. B
2. C

I wanna know why does this happen. Following is my code:-

```
public void onSwipe(int adapterPosition) {
    .
    .
    realm.beginTransaction();
    activity.getReminders().get(adapterPosition).deleteFromRealm();  //activity.getReminders() returns the RealmResults object
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Comment: try using result.deleteFromRealm(/*pass index here*/);

Comment: still getting the same result.

Comment: I guess you need to sort your RealmResults to keep the order you want

Comment: @Maelig yes you are right. I figured this out the same day by sorting the data with respect to the time the realm object is added (by using System.currentTimeInMillis()). It keeps the order i want that way

Comment: @syed_noorullah I posted the answer, please accept it to help anyone coming on your post with the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort your results to keep the order you want. Example from the doc :

```java
result = result.sort("age"); // Sort ascending
result = result.sort("age", Sort.DESCENDING);
```

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sorting